# Black box on chimney near ceiling in cabin

Tags: furnace, chimney

What is the purpose of the black box on the chimney near the ceiling in this cabin?

Location: Nova Scotia, Canada

[image]

I'm not sure what kind of stove it is.

Comment: Do you have any better picture of it from other angles?  First guess is some sort of heat recovery box to extract more heat out, but that's just a guess.  Is there any power going to the box, or labels/markings on other sides?  Was this professionally installed?  It sure looks like (from the picture) a fireplace insert that's been installed as a stand-alone unit (likely not an approved use from the manufacturer).  Especially indicative of this non-approved install is the sketchy tape/banding holding the flex chimney to the rigid vertical section.

Comment: how do you not know what kind of stove that is?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the strapping (looks like electrical tape from this distance) holding the flex pipe to the rigid pipe just above the fireplace itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a transition piece from the single wall flue (rusty steel stovepipe) from the stove to manufactured chimney (2 or 3 wall stainless) being applied in an odd way.

Normally that box would be in your attic space, and the purpose of the box part would be to keep attic insulation away from the chimney pipe inside it.

But this building does not have an attic space - still the manufactured chimney needs a part to transition/terminate into single wall pipe. And perhaps the one that would have looked better doing that for your angled ceiling boards was not in stock.

Answer (score 0):

It looks very much like a twin wall cube flue system, it is designed for low level buildings that are prone to high find conditions, problem here is after 35 years in the heating industry, I have never seen an internal flue termination, all flue systems, (gas, solid fuel or oil), to my knowledge require external flue terminations, as such this can be regarded as immediately dangerous to life. Please take care here.

Comment: I'm quite certain that after 35 years in the heating industry, _you_ know exactly what a "twin wall cube flue system" is without thinking twice about it. Unfortunately, not everyone has your experience (thus the question), so it would be a great improvement to your answer if you were to explain that (or at least do us the courtesy of providing a link to something that explains it). Also, please clarify "prone to high find conditions" - is that supposed to be "prone to high _wind_ conditions"?

Comment: If you claim 35 years in heating and can't see the stainless chimney going through the roof after the box, you need to see your eye doctor.